# Как автоматизировать деплой кода на Heroku?

Tags: git, heroku

Каждый раз ввожу следующие команды:

- git add .
- git commit -am "commit"
- git push heroku master
- heroku ps:scale worker=1

Как это всё выполнять быстрее? В одну строчку

Comment: Добавляя &&? Но быстрее это не станет `git add . && git ... && git ... && heroku ...`

Comment: Лексема "&&" не является допустимым разделителем операторов в этой версии.
+ git add . && git commit -am "make it better" && git push heroku maste .

Comment: тогда добавьте больше информации в ваш вопрос.

Comment: что еще добавить надо? Сейчас я ввожу команды по очереди. 4 штуки. А я хочу чтобы всё выполнилось по очереди, при этом я должен написать все в одну строку

Comment: Куда вы вводите? Какая оболочка используется?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно скопировать и вставить все строчки сразу и нажать Ввод.

Answer (score 0):

Создаете bat (для Windows) или sh файл (для Linux), копируете туда нужные команды и готово. Теперь можно будет запускать один файл, который все сделает.

Судя по сообщению об ошибке, Вы используете PowerShell, можно написать скрипт для него. Просто имя у него обычно заканчивается на ps1 - просто создайте в каталоге файл с подходящим Вам именем, скопируйте туда нужные 4 строки и готово (Но так как это PowerShell, "все для людей", возможно придется [потрогать свойства файла](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58524451/how-to-run-powershell-script-from-ps1-file)

Но можно и в одну строку

```
(git add .) -and (git commit -am "commit") -and (git push heroku master) -and (heroku ps:scale worker=1)
```

Правда у этого способа есть сильный минус - вывод команды не видно.

Но у этих способов есть пара недостатков. Во первых, текст сообщения для коммита будет один и тот же. Это решается просто  - текст сообщения передается как параметр командной стоки, а в самом скрипте пишем так

```
git commit -am "$args[0]"
```

Второе - это то, что все постоянно коммитится. Можно немного перестараться и закоммитить мусор или, что ещё хуже, пароли и явки. Но и это не проблема. Если код разрабатывается с под редактора или ide, то можно просто эти команды добавить туда. И коммит будет средствами IU (тут все просто, может захочется пару раз закоммитить, а команда билд может вызывать полноценный деплой (последние две команды). Может получится даже лучше, чем Вы себе представляете.

Comment: Спасибо. Но ответ оказался куда проще - можно просто скопировать все 4 строки и вставить в powershell. Они выполняться по очереди все